# Проверка наличия и значений поля в таблице БД

Tags: sqlite, php, база-данных

Помогите реализовать данный алгоритм на PHP с СУБД SQLite:

> Если в базе данных SQLite my.db, в
> таблице qwe, есть поле с именем name
> которое равно значению $name, то
> выполняются следующие действия { ... }
> конец.

**Добавлено.**

Скрипт:

```
<?php
if ($_GET["login"]=='') {
 header('Location: index.php?error=wherelogin');
 exit;
}elseif ($_GET["email"]=='') {
 header('Location: index.php?error=whereemail');
 exit;
}elseif ($_GET["pass"]=='') {
 header('Location: index.php?error=wherepass');
 exit;
}
if ($_GET["pass"]==$_GET["pass2"]) {
$dbh = sqlite_open('main.db');
if (!$dbh) {
  die('Failed to open/create database');
}
$res = sqlite_query($dbh, "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='users'");
if (sqlite_num_rows($res) == 0) {
 $res = sqlite_exec($dbh, '
  CREATE TABLE users (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  user_name varchar(16),
  user_sword varchar(32),
  user_email varchar(32));
 ');
}
$res = sqlite_query($dbh, "
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='".sqlite_escape_string($_GET['login'])."'
");
if (($res !== FALSE) and ($res->numRows() > 0)) {
 header('Location: /index.php?error=closelogin');
 exit;
}
$res = sqlite_query($dbh, "
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='".sqlite_escape_string($_GET['email'])."'
");
if (($res !== FALSE) and ($res->numRows() > 0)) {
 header('Location: /index.php?error=closeemail&'.$res);
 exit;
}
$res = sqlite_exec($dbh, "
 INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_sword, user_email)
  VALUES (
  '".sqlite_escape_string($_GET['login'])."',
  '".sqlite_escape_string(md5(md5($_GET['password'])))."',
  '".sqlite_escape_string($_GET['email'])."'
  )
");
header('Location: index.php?sucreg');
}else{
 header('location: index.php?error=failedpassword');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Документация по SQLite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php)

Можно так:

```
$db = new SQLiteDatabase('my.db', 0666, $sqliteerror);
if ($db !== FALSE) { 
    $result = $db->query(
        'select * from qwe where name="'
         . sqlite_escape_string($name)
         . '"'
    );
    if ($result !== FALSE and $result->numRows() > 0) {
        // выполняются следующие действия
    }
    else {
        // Ничего не нашли
    }

}
else {
    die($sqliteerror);
}
```

**Добавлено.**

Исправленная версия:

```
<?php
    // For OO-like escape-string
    class MySQLite extends SQLiteDatabase {
        public function escape ($data) {
                return is_array($data) ? array_map("sqlite_escape_string", $data) : sqlite_escape_string($data);
        }
    }


    if (empty($_GET)) {
        die("Invalid context for this script\n");
    }
    elseif ($_GET["login"] == '') {

        header('Location: index.php?error=wherelogin');

        exit;

    }
    elseif ($_GET["email"] == '') {

        header('Location: index.php?error=whereemail');

        exit;

    }
    elseif ($_GET["pass"] == '' || $_GET["pass2"] == '') {

        header('Location: index.php?error=wherepass');

        exit;

    }
    elseif ($_GET["pass"] == $_GET["pass2"]) {
        $dbh = MySQLite('main.db', 0666, $error);



        if (!$dbh) {

            die('Failed to open/create database: ' . $error . "\n");

        }


        $res = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='users'");

        if ($res->numRows() == 0) {

            $res = $dbh->query(
                'CREATE TABLE users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, user_name varchar(16), user_sword varchar(32), user_email varchar(32));'
            );
            if ($res === FALSE) {
                die("Error create table 'users'\n");
            }

        }


        $res = $dbh->query( 
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='"
            . $dbh->escape($_GET['login'])
            . "'"
        );

        if ($res !== FALSE and $res->numRows() > 0) {

            header('Location: /index.php?error=closelogin');

            exit;

        }


        $res = $dbh->query(
            "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_email='"
            . $dbh->escape($_GET['email'])
            . "'"
        );

        if ($res !== FALSE and $res->numRows() > 0) {

            header('Location: /index.php?error=closeemail');

            exit;

        }


        $res = $dbh->query(
            "INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_sword, user_email) VALUES ('"
            . $dbh->escape($_GET['login'])
            . "','"
            . $dbh->escape(md5(md5($_GET['password'])))
            . "','"
            . $dbh->escape($_GET['email'])
            . "')"
        );

        header('Location: index.php?sucreg');

    }
    else {

        header('location: index.php?error=failedpassword');

    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но выдаёт ошибку: TypeError $res.numRow is not a function.
Вот код: http://narod.ru/disk/32982653001/script.php.html

P.S. Не ругайте сильно, так как с PHP работаю не больше месяца.

Comment: Посмотрел скрипт, понял ошибку - смешение ООП и функционального стиля, исправленная версия [здесь][1].

Соответственно исправляю ответ.

  [1]: https://gist.github.com/1414946

Comment: Спасибо большое.
Но я как то более понятное решение, для себя, нашёл такое:

$res=sqlite_query($dbh, "SELECT * FROM users");
while ($row=sqlite_fetch_array($res)) {
 if ($row["user_name"]==$_GET["login"]) {
  //Тут код если найден такой же логин
 }
 if ($row["user_email"]==$_GET["email"]) {
  //Тут код если найден такой же емаил
 }
}

Но всё ровно большое спасибо! :)

Comment: @Никита Рабыкин, никогда так не делайте))) Вы первым запросом грузите всю таблицу в память, у вас даже на сотн-тысяче юзеров будут адовы тормоза и беседы с хостером)

Comment: @Sh4dow, спасибо за совет, воспользуюсь вариантом от @chernomyrdin'а, которому, опять же, большое спасибо за помощь :)